# Show records that are only for the current user

Tags: ms-access, vba, office365, ms-office

I have an Access Database that I have the user log into before entry. When the login is completed successfully it saves their username as TempVars("User"). I have 2 tables. A user table that stores the UserID, username, password, and various contact information. I also have a data table where asset records are kept. The username will be specified in a username field of the data table which is in a relationship with the username field in the user table.

What I want to do is have it so that only the currently logged in user can see their own records in a form. I am new to Access VBA so I am unable to figure this out by myself.

Okay I think I have figured this out. I put the table into a query and that stopped the Add Parameter popup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should handle this by entirely controlling your forms' recordsource with VBA (and SQL). That requires some programming skills.

Thta's a long story. Here's the short version:

Select your form, and add a **On Load** Event (code)

The code should be something like

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

    dim strSQL as string 

    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM the_table WHERE UserID=" & your_user_variable

    debug.print strSQL 

    Me.RecordSource = strSQL

End Sub
```

Comment: Okay, I have added that into the Form_load. Now it shows me a dialog box with a text input when I go to the form. Putting in noting and clicking okay will not show and records and clicking cancel will just open the form with all records showing.

Comment: Okay If I enter a username it will just populate with that user. I just need to figure out how to do it automatically.

Comment: you have to replace the_current_user_id with the variable handling the current . userid, of course. Dont you have that ?

Comment: I have replaced it with Tempvars("User"). I have also tried TempVars!User as the other answer suggested.

Comment: check my adapted answer, I have added some code that will print the SQL instruction (and your variable) in the console. That will help you to understand what happens

Comment: I have edited my description with my current formatting. [It will still bring up the dialog box with the same behaviors that I have noted before.](https://imgur.com/tZg0WHt)

Comment: I put the table in a query and recreated the form and it seems to work okay now. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In queries, you refer to TempVars using the bang notation:

```
Where SomeProperty = TempVars!User
```

While you could go the VBA way, I certainly don't recommend it if it can be solved through SQL alone